# Salesforce datamodel from Erwin DDL

Tags: salesforce, erwin

I'm relatively new to salesforce - trying to create a custom application with 20+ custom objects, fields, relationships etc.

I have built the physical model in Erwin data modeller. Is it possible to use DDL from erwin to create data model in sales force?

There's a create objects from spreadsheet option in salesforce

but is there a better way of maintaining datamodel in erwin but have a continuous deployment to salesforce model?

Comment: Can the DDL be exported as something you can use to construct XML similar to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm ?

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if i can use ddl to export as per the format in the link you shared..  if anyone has done this already, would be good to know...